# Lambda function as node.js module

Tags: node.js, firebase, lambda, module

The idea below is making the below lambda function to run has a node module

Node.js Server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = require('http').Server(app);
//var socketIoServer = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(2006, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + 2006);
});
require('./lambdaFunction/function').startLambdaFunction()
```

And the lambda function i have made as node.js module is as below:

```
'use strict';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

let atlas_connection_uri;
let cachedDb = null;

let firebase = require('firebase');

exports.handler= function(event, context,callback)
{

    // var uri = process.env['MONGODB_ATLAS_CLUSTER_URI'];
    var uri = "mongodb://163.172.131.83:28018/harmanconnectedcar";
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    firebase.initializeApp({
        serviceAccount: {},
        databaseURL: "https://harmanconnectedcar-180411.firebaseio.com/"
    });


    var eventDataRef = firebase.database().ref('testTable');
    eventDataRef.on('child_changed', function(child,prev) {
        console.log("*************inside fucntion**********************")
        // all records after the last continue to invoke this function

        var lastKey = Object.keys(child.val()).sort().reverse()[0];
        var eventDetectedData = child.val()[lastKey];
        console.log(eventDetectedData);



    });

};


module.exports = {startLambdaFunction: exports.handler};
```

The module exported is invoke but I am getting the error has:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop' of undefined
```

***The reason i am doing so is lambda function exits after 30 seconds i want to running function for unlimited time i am just trying to do it***

By creating a node.js server and invoking the lambda function as module

Just a though please Give some inputs and ideas to accomplish i might be completely wrong in doing just a though please give some input

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your lambda function with no arguments. When you call it in this line:

```
require('./lambdaFunction/function').startLambdaFunction()
```

you need to pass some arguments into it that look like what it would get if it were actually running on lambda.

```
require('./lambdaFunction/function').startLambdaFunction(event, context, callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really grasp what you're trying to accomplish, but here's whats going wrong.

You're exporting a function that requires three parameters:

```
exports.handler= function(event, context, callback)
```

But.. you're calling the function without arguments causing context to be undefined when you try to set its property `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` to `false`.

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

You could either pass three arguments when you require the `./lambdaFunction/function`

```
require('./lambdaFunction/function').startLambdaFunction() /*Pass three arguments here*/
```

..or you can export the function without parameters and initialize them locally.